# How to make copy of the tree for the iterative postOrder traversal to protect the Tree

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

Iterative PostOrder traversal deletes the Whole tree, in Scala we have :

```
override def clone():BinarySearchTree=
{
  return new BinarySearchTree(root.clone())
}
```

Then we copy the whole tree by using :

```
def postorder(tnode:TreeNode) 
{    
   var tcnode=tnode.clone
}
```

**now tcnode have the copy of the whole tree.**
**But I want to do the same in python I tried using :**

```
import copy
def postOrder(self, tnode):
    tcnode = copy.copy(tnode)
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `tcnode=copy.deepcopy(tnode)` because deepcopy doesn't change the original tree but in your case you are using Shallow copy in this case it will change the original tree, for more information on deepcopy[Difference between DeepCopy and Shallow copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/)